# VBA value larger than x days x hours

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a VBA script for data that is being extracted from a website. Now I am struggling with hiding the rows that are larger than a certain amount of days.

The reason I struggle is because the format is as:

- 0d 8h 2m 29s
- 105d 19h 4m 19s
- 10d 17h 4m 48s

I have been browsing the internet but I've been unable to find any code that works with values without a separator. Usually time has a ":" separator. I tried to leave it out but I did't get my code to work.

My code looks like:

```
    Dim BooBoo As Long, TheEnd As Long
            
    'Tell me where is the end!
    TheEnd = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Play it where
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
       For BooBoo = 2 To TheEnd
          'Anything in column E that is older than 3 days, has to be hidden
    
          If .Cells(BooBoo, "E").Value > "3d 0h 0m 0s" Then
              .Rows(BooBoo).EntireRow.Hidden = True
              If Rows(BooBoo).Hidden = True Then Rows(BooBoo).EntireRow.Delete
          End If
       Next
    End With
```

I feel I'm approaching this the wrong way. Hopefully someone can help me with this.

Regards,
Sebastian

Comment: Quick thought - have you tried checking if the left two characters are equal to "0d"/"1d"/"2d"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using of this function, please:

```
Private Function TotalReference(strTime As String) As Double 'hours
    Dim arrD As Variant
    arrD = Split(strTime, " ")
    TotalReference = Split(arrD(0), "d")(0) * 24 + Split(arrD(1), _
       "h")(0) + Split(arrD(2), "m")(0) / 60 + Split(arrD(3), "s")(0) / 3600
End Function
```

You can test it in the next way:

```
Sub testHideBiggerDate()
  Dim x As String
  x = "3d 2h 20m 50s"
  Debug.Print TotalReference(x)
End Sub
```

And in your code you can use it in this way:

```
If TotalReference(.Cells(BooBoo, "E").Value) > TotalReference("3d 0h 0m 0s") Then
```

Besides that, your code firstly hide the row then check if it is hidden and delete it. Why hiding it first...? And using `Rows(BooBoo).Hidden = True` will check the row of the active sheet, not the one your code processes, if it is not activate. You should also use: `.Rows(BooBoo).Hidden = True`.

Your code would like in this way:

```
Sub compareDatevalues()
 Dim BooBoo As Long, TheEnd As Long
 
    TheEnd = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
       For BooBoo = 2 To TheEnd
          'Anything in column E that is older than 3 days, has to be hidden
          If TotalReference(.Cells(BooBoo, "E").Value) > TotalReference("3d 0h 0m 0s") Then 'or > 72
              .Rows(BooBoo).EntireRow.Hidden = True
              If .Rows(BooBoo).Hidden = True Then Rows(BooBoo).EntireRow.Delete 'why to delete it in two phases?
          End If
       Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: In my code the rule for hiding and deleting has been commented out. Didn't come over when I posted the code here.

Comment: @SeMo: I do not understand your point... When you say "In my code" aren't you referring to the one in your question? This is what we check here. But, never-mind... Did you test the above suggested function? It allows you to change the reference ("3d 0h 0m 0s") in let us say, "3d 12h 0m 0s", for some cases, if you would want/need that...

Comment: Tested your code. Works like a charm. Thanks for the help!

Comment: With "in my code" I meant the script that's on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can quite easily extract number of days from your string and then compare integers. I assume that you do not want to take into account also hours etc.

```
    Dim BooBoo As Long, TheEnd As Long
            
    'Tell me where is the end!
    TheEnd = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Play it where
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
    For BooBoo = 2 To TheEnd
    'Anything in column E that is older than 3 days, has to be hidden
    
    If Mid(.Cells(BooBoo, "E"), 1, WorksheetFunction.Find("d", .Cells(BooBoo, "E").Value) - 1) * 1 > 3 Then
    .Rows(BooBoo).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    If Rows(BooBoo).Hidden = True Then Rows(BooBoo).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    Next
    End With
```